Add a new android activity to flutter app
I have build this flutter app which relies on using an alarm to function properly, everything works fine and the alarm triggers as expected, the only problem am facing now is the app has became fully able to bypass the screen lock if the phone is closed while the app is open, this is due to me using this two in the android manifest file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"/>
and
android:showWhenLocked="true
these 2 attributes are necessary for the alarm to trigger while the phone is closed, so i cannot remove them, so the only possible solution i can think of is to create a new activity only for the alarm screen, so the previous attributes doesn't corrupt the rest of the app, but i have never tried such a thing and couldn't find any help online
